# How to remove backward (Ctrl+H) functionality from TextField?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, textfield

I have an application which has menubar.
This menubar has a menuitem with the Ctrl+H accelerator.
The problem is that when a TextField (or PasswordField) is focused, it catch the Ctrl+H event to make a backward deletion.

Does someone have a trick to prevent the textfield from catching this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code....it will prevent TextBox from backward remove(Ctrl+H).

```
   txtBox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent t) {           
            if(t.getCode()==KeyCode.H && t.isControlDown() )
            {                                                

               t.consume();
            }                           
    }});
```

Comment: thanks Yogesh. The textfield doesn't react on Ctrl+H event but the event is consumed so the menuBar can't catch it... it must call the menuBar myself in the textfield handler.

Comment: put you work statement into above this if statement.
suppose you want to call menu bar item....do it manually..
write down code which is supposed to be executed on the menu item click.